# How to switch to a different WiFi channel?

Tags: linux, wifi, wifi-hotspot, iw

I am running a server sending data from a linux embedded device which is hosting its own network using a network module. It is running on an iMX7 processor connected to a network module.

The problem that I am facing is that my host is always unluckily choosing a random channel that is quite noisy and crowded and because of this, my data transfer is having some latencies.

My question is: is there a linux command or a programatic way to switch the wifi channel?

I can run `iwlist p2p-wlan0-0 scan | grep \(Channel` to see the available channels on that interface. But is there a way to enforce my interface which is `p2p-wlan0-0` to choose a specific channel like channel 49 for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you're using hostapd then you could set the desired channel in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`: `channel=7` taken from: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/software_access_point
- Then there's `wifi-ap.config` in Ubuntu: `wifi-ap.config set wifi.channel=8`

Comment: Yes, I am using `hostapd.conf`. But its located in `/etc/hostapd.conf` for me. Nevermind this part. I set `channel=7` then it does not chose that channel 48. That is very interesting. May be its not allowed to choose which ever channel it wants to. Is there a allowed channels list that I should be aware of. Thanks a million for this useful answer by the way.

Comment: `iwlist wlan0 freq` (p2p-wlan0-0 in your case) should show you the available channels.

Comment: Accepting your answer. Thanks a bunch. I cannot make it choose channel 40 by setting `channel=40` but if I set it to like `channel=30`, it chooses 40. It seems like there is some logic to choose channel nearest to the number I have requested on hosapd.conf. I need to dig deeper but this gives me a way to affect the channel at least. Thanks a lot again